# What does "psql: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)" actually mean?

Tags: postgresql, scripting, psql, bash

I have a question regarding following output:

```
[nikola@192 ~] $ sudo su - postgres
[postgres@192 ~] $ psql dvdrental postgres
psql: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)
psql: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)
psql (11.7, server 11.8)
Type "help" for help.

dvdrental=#
```

What do following two messages stand for and why? Messages I am asking about:

1. `psql: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)`
2. `psql (11.7, server 11.8)` - BTW, for this `psql --version` command I get following output:
   `psql (PostgreSQL) 11.8` (**had to install** PostgreSQL Server version 11.7 in order to perform command such as `\dt` and `\l`)
   ...and also this output:

> ```
> postgres=# select * FROM version();
>                                                 version                                                 
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>  PostgreSQL 11.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2), 64-bit
> (1 row)
> ```

P.S. I'm running PostgreSQL 11.8 on Fedora 30.

**UPDATE1:**
As requested by @LaurenzAlbe output for `rpm -qa|grep postgres` command is:

```
[nikola@192 ~] $ rpm -qa|grep postgres
postgresql-11.7-2.fc30.x86_64
postgresql11-11.8-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
postgresql11-libs-11.8-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
postgresql11-server-11.8-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
postgresql-server-11.7-2.fc30.x86_64
```

**UPDATE2**:

I've ran `dnf remove postgresql postgresql-server` command -> databases are still there and I can access them via **pgAdmin4** and **psql: /usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql** message is no longer showing up. But, there is now new issue -> when I access **postgres shell** in terminal using `sudo su - postgres` command and then perform `psql some-database-name postgres` I get message

> bash: psql: command not found... 
> Install package 'postgresql' to provide command 'psql'? [N/y]

I presume this is asking me to install AGAIN **Fedora package** which in 1st place I am trying to get rid off (to not show psql: */usr/pgsql-11/lib/libpq.so.5: no version information available (required by psql)* message).

Any suggestion how to solve this without installing Fedora package but from **PostgreSQL Global Development group**?

**P.S.** BTW, I've installed Postgres server by following [this](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-fedora/) link which uses PGDG packages (but something didn't work right on my machine and I guess I've been offered by Fedora30 OS to install Fedora packages which is obviously what I did :) ).

Comment: Could you add the result of this to the question: `rpm -qa|grep postgres`

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I've updated my question as you asked. Please take a look

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have installed a mixture of packets: some from the Fedora distribution, some from the PostgreSQL Global Development group.

These don't work well together. In particular, you have `psql` from the Fedora packages in the `PATH`, but `libpq` from the PGDG packages is on the library path.

That explains your question #2.

Ad question #1: that warning is printed if the library version of the installed library is lower than the one the software was linked with.

Remove the Fedora packages to get rid of the problem:

```
dnf remove postgresql postgresql-server
```

I hope that puts the correct `psql` on your `PATH`; if not, reinstall the `postgresql11` package.

Comment: Will removing Fedora packages effect my pgAdmin4 configuration...I mean will I loose all my databases (if yes what should I do to save them -> only perform `pg_dump` for all databases for my postgresql cluster or something else)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Removing packages won't remove a database, but you should definitely figure out which software is running your database. That might require someone who knows something about PostgreSQL. Dumping the database and restoring it afterwards is the safe way.

Comment: I will definitely backup my databases, but is there any command to execute in terminal in order to find out which software is running my database? BTW, I'm using Postgres as my primary database for projects used for my Master Thesis.

Comment: The `ps` command will show that.

Comment: Tried what you suggested (to remove Fedora packages). Please take a look on updated question under **UPDATE2** section

Comment: Hi Laurenz, I've managed to reach a solution with your help and by performing some additional steps. You can check my answer and add some suggestion if you find something there is to improve (and +1 upvote it if it's OK :) ). Thanks once again.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: To confirm the above, I had a mismatch between `libpq` which was installed from the PGDG packages and `postgresql` from the Fedora packages. I ran `dnf remove postgresql postgresql-server` which also removed `libpq` because it is is a dependency, then installed both with `dnf install postgresql postgresql-server`. I fired up the server, it detected the previous installation, and the error was gone.

Answer (score 2):

After experimenting and trying out suggestions made by @Laurenz Albe I've managed to reach solution.

Solution after performing mentioned steps in my question to do one more additional step which is to run `sudo dnf reinstall pacakage_name` (`package_name` is one of three below mentioned packages ) command for following packages:

```
[nikola@192 ~] $ rpm -qa|grep postgres
postgresql11-11.8-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
postgresql11-libs-11.8-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
postgresql11-server-11.8-1PGDG.f30.x86_64
```

After that everything works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

This question has been answered so so this answer is intended to be a complement.

I found the same problem running postgres version 13 on CentOS 8. As pointed out before, libpq's version is mismatched and comes from a different repository.

```
#  dnf info --installed libpq* postgresql*
Installed Packages
Name         : libpq5
Version      : 14.2
Release      : 42PGDG.rhel8
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 791 k
Source       : libpq5-14.2-42PGDG.rhel8.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : pgdg-common
...
    
Name         : postgresql
Version      : 13.5
Release      : 1.module_el8.5.0+1062+8eba5f44
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 5.5 M
Source       : postgresql-13.5-1.module_el8.5.0+1062+8eba5f44.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : appstream
...
    
Name         : postgresql-server
Version      : 13.5
Release      : 1.module_el8.5.0+1062+8eba5f44
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 22 M
Source       : postgresql-13.5-1.module_el8.5.0+1062+8eba5f44.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : appstream
...
```

This problem was solved by uninstalling the library

```
# rpm -e --nodeps libpq5
```

*Note: Using "dnf" will attempt to remove postgresql and postgresql-server (which may be fine in many cases) and we would need to install them again. By using "rpm" we don't touch them so we don't have to reinstall.*

and finally installing the correct one.

```
# dnf install libpq-13.3-1.el8_4.x86_64
```

Now everything matches

```
#  dnf info --installed libpq* postgresql*
Installed Packages
Name         : libpq
Version      : 13.3
Release      : 1.el8_4
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 720 k
Source       : libpq-13.3-1.el8_4.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : appstream
...

Name         : postgresql
Version      : 13.5
Release      : 1.module_el8.5.0+1062+8eba5f44
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 5.5 M
Source       : postgresql-13.5-1.module_el8.5.0+1062+8eba5f44.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : appstream
...

Name         : postgresql-server
Version      : 13.5
Release      : 1.module_el8.5.0+1062+8eba5f44
Architecture : x86_64
Size         : 22 M
Source       : postgresql-13.5-1.module_el8.5.0+1062+8eba5f44.src.rpm
Repository   : @System
From repo    : appstream
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very old post and people have already answered(specifically Laurenz Albe).
I followed what Laurenz Albe has mentioned and found that in my /etc/yum.repos.d  there was a repo location from redhat linux which was again and again installing conflicting library.
I just commented out all entries for postgres in yum repos and tried doing fresh install of postgresql-server after uninstalling as mentioned by Laurenz Albe. It helped me to do all compatible package install. The error was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

See interference between versions:

> psql (11.7, server 11.8)

This can be due to module vs. pgdg installation (see [link1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545635/install-postgresql-12-in-centos-8-got-no-match-for-argument-postgresql12) and [link2](https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=77794) at the bottom).

Comment: I think this was covered in the existing answer?

Comment: I don't see "module" and "pgdg" mentioned in the answer, imho they are important keywords